# Incremental table index

Tags: sql

In all SQL tables I'm using incremental index with name id. I'm not sure I'm right since I have heard that some SQL servers increment it's records as default. I'm right? How to get these default increment fields values then in different SQL servers?

Another question in case I use my own id - what data type I should use for this field? Currently I'm using int type.

Comment: could you please tag the relevant RDBMS

Comment: The 1st question is well documented in the redpective manuals. The answer to the 2nd is it depends on your business requirements.

Comment: If you're really using MySQL, SQL Server, PostgeSQL and SQLite, that should be explained in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you are absolutely right. It is very good practice to have an incremental Identity ID column for clustered index.
However, it might depend on your business process. In case of massive loads into the table you might have clustered Index contention. In that case you might have to use GUID or special scenarios, but it is pretty rare case.

2nd question: You have to use whole numbers for your ID and the size depends on number of records in the table. For instance if you have table "Gender" you can use "**TINYINT**" (1 byte). It contains values from 0 to 255.
If you have table "Work Period" (for a daily recordings) you are OK with "**SMALLINT**" (2 bytes). It contains values from -32,768 to 32,767.
In most of other cases you use type "**INT**"
In case your boss says it won't be enough you might use "**BIGINT**", but in that case you probably will fight contention.

Here is how to declare these values:

```
ID TINYINT IDENTITY(0,1)
ID SMALLINT IDENTITY(-32768,1)
ID INT IDENTITY(-2147483648,1)
ID BIGINT IDENTITY(-9223372036854775808,1)
```